# PyTorch warning about using a non-full backward hook when the forward contains multiple autograd Nodes

Tags: python, pytorch, hook, autograd

After a recent upgrade, when running my PyTorch loop, I now get the warning

> Using a non-full backward hook when the forward contains multiple autograd Nodes`".

The training still runs and completes, but I am unsure where I am supposed to place the `register_full_backward_hook` function.

I have tried adding it to each of the layers in my neural network but this gives further errors about using different hooks.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch version 1.8.0 deprecated [`register_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_backward_hook#torch.nn.Module.register_backward_hook) ([source code](http://module.html#Module.register_backward_hook)) in favor of [`register_full_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_backward_hook#torch.nn.Module.register_full_backward_hook) ([source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L925)).

You can find it in the patch notes here: *[Deprecated old style `nn.Module` backward hooks](https://newreleases.io/project/github/pytorch/pytorch/release/v1.8.0) (PR [#46163](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/46163))*

The warning you're getting:

> Using a non-full backward hook when the forward contains multiple autograd Nodes is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. This hook will be missing some `grad_input`. Please use `register_full_backward_hook` to get the documented behavior.

Simply indicates that you should replace all `register_backward_hook` calls with `register_full_backward_hook` in your code to get the behavior described in the documentation page.

Comment: I have the same problem. @ivan we didn't specifically used "register_backward_hook" in our code. It's from some pytorch internal library. Should we change pytorch libraries?

Comment: Which version of PyTorch are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using 1.13.