# Is layer_activation (register_forward_hook) the same as gradient?

Tags: pytorch, gradient

I was wondering if the intermediate layer output initialised by register_forward_hook is the same as the gradient of the intermediate output wrt the image?

Comment: What do you mean by "*intermediate layer output* ***initialized*** *by `register_forward_hook`"*?

Comment: When I use Pytorch, there is a function called register_forward_hook that allows you to get the output of a specific layer. I was wondering if this intermediate layer output is the same as getting the gradient of the layer.

Comment: No, the "activation" is the output of the layer, but the gradient of this layer with respect to its input(s) is a different thing! You would need a different hook to access this information since it is computed during the backward pass, ***not the forward pass***: here applying [`register_module_full_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_full_backward_hook.html) on the module is required to do such thing. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan!! That helps a lot :) 
Do you perhaps have an example of how to implement it? I can't seem to find anything online. At the moment I implemented it as follows:

def backward_hook(module, grad_input, grad_output):
        print('grad_output:', grad_output)
for name, layer in model.named_modules(): 
            layer.register_module_full_backward_hook(backward_hook)
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    model.eval()

Comment: for ind, (img, label) in enumerate(loader):
        img.requires_grad=True
        label = label.type(torch.LongTensor)
        img, label = label.to(device).float(), label.to(device)
        output = model(img)
        loss = loss_fn(output.float(), label.squeeze())
        loss.backward()

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as initialising the register_module_full_backward_hook is wrong I believe.

Comment: Oups, sorry it should be [`register_full_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_full_backward_hook#torch.nn.Module.register_full_backward_hook) and not [`register_module_full_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_full_backward_hook.html). I have written an answer below, hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach a callback function on a given module with [`nn.Module.register_full_backward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=register_full_backward_hook#torch.nn.Module.register_full_backward_hook) to hook onto the backward pass of that layer. This allows you to access the gradient.

Here is a minimal example, define the hook as you did:

```
def backward_hook(module, grad_input, grad_output):
    print('grad_output:', grad_output)
```

Initialize your model and attach the hook on its layers

```
>>> model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10, 5), nn.Linear(5, 2))
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=5, bias=True)
  (1): Linear(in_features=5, out_features=2, bias=True)
)

>>> for name, layer in model.named_children():
...     print(f'hook onto {name}')
...     layer.register_full_backward_hook(backward_hook)
hook onto 0
hook onto 1
```

Perform an inference:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(5, 10)
>>> y = model(x).mean()
```

Perform the backward pass:

```
>>> y.backward()
grad_output: (tensor([[0.1000, 0.1000],
        [0.1000, 0.1000],
        [0.1000, 0.1000],
        [0.1000, 0.1000],
        [0.1000, 0.1000]]),)
grad_output: (tensor([[ 0.0135,  0.0141, -0.0468, -0.0378, -0.0123],
        [ 0.0135,  0.0141, -0.0468, -0.0378, -0.0123],
        [ 0.0135,  0.0141, -0.0468, -0.0378, -0.0123],
        [ 0.0135,  0.0141, -0.0468, -0.0378, -0.0123],
        [ 0.0135,  0.0141, -0.0468, -0.0378, -0.0123]]),)
```

---

For more examples, you can look at my other answers related to `register_full_backward_hook`:

- [*Using a non-full backward hook when the forward contains multiple Autograd nodes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994662/pytorch-warning-about-using-a-non-full-backward-hook-when-the-forward-contains-m/68972354#68972354)
- [*How to create a PyTorch hook with conditions?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817536/how-to-create-a-pytorch-hook-with-conditions/69818208#69818208)
- [*How to get all the tensors in a graph?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878476/how-to-get-all-the-tensors-in-a-graph/65647597#65647597)